# Conditional cast from String to NSString always succeeds

Tags: swift, nsstring

I'm trying to eliminate this warning. I get the warning under this line:

```
let removeHashTag = (currentText as? NSString)?.substring(from: 1)
```

I know it already in a string format, and but when I tried typing it won't give me the option to substring.

```
func searchGetTextAutoComplete(_ text: String?) {
    var currentText: String

    if text == nil {
        ViewAnimation.move(tableView, withAlpha: 0.0)
        print("textfield is nil")
    } else {
        if (text?.count ?? 0) == 0 {
            ViewAnimation.move(tableView, withAlpha: 0.0)
            print("textfield has zero length")
        } else {
            currentText = text ?? ""

            // # included in the beggining of the string
            //MARK: you dont needs to downcasted if it already a string
            if (text?.count ?? 0) > 1 {
                let removeHashTag = (currentText as? NSString)?.substring(from: 1)

                SketchManager.shared()?.searchTagsOrUsername(removeHashTag, withCompletion: { success, message, searchResultDic in

                    if success {
                        self.followersArray = (searchResultDic?["follower"] as? [String])!
                        let resultArray = searchResultDic?["result"] as? [Any]
                        //                        NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);

                        if resultArray?.count == 0 {
                            self.noResultsPlacehoder.isHidden = false
                            ViewAnimation.move(self.tableView, withAlpha: 0.0)
                        } else {
                            self.itemsArray.removeAll()

                            for dic in resultArray as? [[String : Any]] ?? [] {

                                self.itemsArray.append(dic)
                            }

                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                            ViewAnimation.move(self.tableView, withAlpha: 1.0)
                            self.noResultsPlacehoder.isHidden = true
                        }
                    }
                })
            } else {
                noResultsPlacehoder.isHidden = false
                ViewAnimation.move(tableView, withAlpha: 0.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to cast to `NSString` at all? `String` has methods to get substrings.

Comment: that what i thought but it wont give me that option

Answer (score 0):

While you are using constant value for substring from 1 you can easily use

```
let removedHashTag = currentText.dropFirst()
let editedString = String(removedHashTag)
```

Comment: i did that but then it gave me an error of Cannot convert value of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') to expected argument type 'String?'

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the question marks.

```
(currentText as NSString).substring(from: 1)
```

Even better, don't cast to NSString at all. Swift String gives you the same powers:

```
currentText.suffix(currentText.count-1)
```